# How to return an object after insert with sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi

I would like to retrieve the object after inserting it into the database, by object I mean the Base class.
Some examples:

```py
class EdaToken(Base):

    __tablename__ = "eda_token"

    """id, primary key"""
    id = Column(
        Integer(),
        primary_key=True
    )
#... etc etc
```

this works, return an EdaToken object:

```py
   @classmethod
    async def get_all(cls) -> List['EdaToken']:
        """
        Get all records in database
        """
        async with get_session() as conn:
            result =  await conn.execute(
                select(EdaToken)
            )
        return result.scalars().all()
```

The problem is in the insert:

```py
#various tests
    @classmethod
    async def create_eda_token(
            cls,
            token: EdaTokenInputOnCreate
    ) -> 'EdaToken':
        """
        Create a token and returning its new id
        """
        async with get_session() as conn:
            result = await conn.execute(
               insert(EdaToken).values(label=token.label,token=token.token)
            )
        return result.scalars().unique().first() #??
```

What I'd like to return is the new database entry as an EdaToken object.

Error:

```
<sqlalchemy.engine.cursor.CursorResult object at 0x7fedd7c24250>
'CursorResult' object has no attribute 'id'
```

Another test:

doesn't seem to work, though, it only allows me to enter a new token once, all new tokens are not entered and it always returns the previous token, the only one that is entered.

```py
   @classmethod
    async def create_eda_token(cls, token: EdaTokenInputOnCreate) -> 'EdaToken':
            """
            Create a token and returning its new id
            """
            async with get_session() as conn:
                result = await conn.execute(
                    insert(EdaToken).values(label=token.label,token=token.token).returning(EdaToken)
                )
                await conn.flush()
                token_id = result.scalars().unique().first()
                result = await conn.execute(
                    select(EdaToken).where(EdaToken.id == token_id)
                )
            return result.scalars().unique().first()
```

`psycopg2==2.9.3`
`sqlalchemy==1.4.46`
`asyncpg==0.27.0`

Comment: Have you tried selecting the object after inserting it? The `result` object should have a `.inserted_primary_key` property that you can use to get the generated id of the last insertion.

Comment: Hi @MatsLindh using scalar on result, I can retrieve the id, what I'm interested in is the return of the EdaToken object, is possible after an insert.

Comment: Yes, query the database for the object as you do with the select above.

Comment: @MatsLindh Can't I do it directly from the insert? Or does the insert only return me the id? I'll try it out and edit the answer.

Comment: No, an insert does not return the whole row that the insert resulted in for most RDBM-es (or their drivers - except for possibly doing an additional SELECT to retrieve the row based on the returned primary key) that I'm familiar with, only the primary key is usually returned by database drivers (implementations will vary)

Comment: Why aren't you using the typical ORM pattern? `new_token = EdaToken(…)`, then `session.add(new_token)`, followed by `session.flush()` or `session.commit()`. That will insert the row into the database and you still have the `new_token` object to work with.

Comment: Hi @GordThompson with get_session() or engine.begin()?

Comment: Not `engine.begin()` because that does not return a Session.

Comment: @GordThompson 
```             
async with get_session() as conn:
                new_token_id = EdaToken(label=token.label,token=token.token)
                result = await conn.add(new_token_id)
                await conn.flush()
```
``` "object NoneType can't be used in 'await' expression"```

Comment: `.add()` and `.add_all()` do not need `await`. See the example [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/_modules/examples/asyncio/async_orm.html).

Comment: thank @GordThompson i have changed my answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the solution, although I don't like it.
Thanks to @MatsLindh

```py
    @classmethod
    async def create_eda_token(cls, token: EdaTokenInputOnCreate) -> 'EdaToken':
            """
            Create a token and returning a new EdaToken instance
            """
            async with engine.begin() as conn:
                result = await conn.execute(
                    insert(EdaToken).values(label=token.label,token=token.token).returning(EdaToken)
                )
                await conn.commit()

            async with get_session() as conn:
                token_id = result.scalars().unique().first()
                result = await conn.execute(
                    select(EdaToken).where(EdaToken.id == token_id)
                )
            return result.scalars().unique().first()
```

New solution thanks to @GordThompson

```py
    @classmethod
    async def create_eda_token(cls, token: EdaTokenInputOnCreate) -> 'EdaToken':
            """
            Create a token and returning a new EdaToken instance <--
            """

            async with get_session() as conn:
                new_token_id = EdaToken(label=token.label,token=token.token)
                conn.add(new_token_id)
                await conn.commit()

            return new_token_id
```